# TkInter: transport variable between two buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, time, scope

Can someone tell me if it's possible to transport a variable between two buttons inside tkinter!? For example: I want to measure the time between pressing two buttons and print it to a label...

```
from tkinter import *
import time

start_time = 0.0

...
def press_start():
    start_time = time.time()

def press_end():
    estimated_time = time.time() - start_time
    lbl_time.config(text=f"Estimated time: {estimated_time }")

...
btn_start = Button(text="Start", command=press_start)
btn_end = Button(text="Start", command=press_end)
lbl_time = Label()
...
```

Comment: Add `global start_time` to the start of `press_start`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `press_start` function only modifies `start_time` in the function scope. `start_time` *outside* of the function still references `0.0`.

```
def press_start():
    start_time = time.time() 
    print(start_time) # would still output time.time()
print(start_time) # outputs 0.0
```

Use the `global` keyword like this:

```
def press_start():
    global start_time
    start_time = time.time()
print(start_time) # outputs time.time() now
```

Relevant topics that I suggest reading into are [*references*](https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-references/) and *[variable scopes](https://www.askpython.com/python/variable-scopes-in-python)*

Comment: all is great and stuff just you could add maybe a few links to the topics you mentioned so that people can easier find them, it is not necessary since you already mentioned what to look for, but topics as links would be the cherry on the cherry on the cake